# populate text boxes based on drop down box selection

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Not done any programming for about 5 years so im a little rusty on this one.

I am building an Asset management system to make my job easier but am struggling on a few things.

What i have so far is the DB setup and populated with a small amount of data, The main site itself is built and the basic select statements to a gridview of any data currently in the system for that particular page/search and i also have an insert statement that is populating the relevant tables based on data filed in on a form on that page. All these functions are working seamlessly.

The problem i have is that one field that needs to be populated for the insert statement needs to populate based upon the selection that is being made from a drop down box in the same form.

i.e.

An Asset that is being registered into the system has an Asset Type (the type details are contained within a parent table Asset_Type) the form has 3 fields for display purposes (one of these fields will need to return an entry to the Asset table in the database from the form, this is working) that are taken from the Asset_Type table, the other fields only relate to the Asset table itself.

What i am trying to achieve is that a user goes to the page and sees a list of Assets registered (this is working) they then need to add a new asset by filling in a form lower down on the page (for is there and writes to DB) on this form is a drop down menu that queries the Asset_Type table and allows the user to select the Type by name (this works)

What i now need to get working is for the 2 other fields to populate based on what Asset type is selected.

These fields are currently textboxes in the form but can be changed if required.

The code i have behind the page is below:

```
Protected Sub Name_Model_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Name_Model.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AssetManagementConnectionString").ToString())
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()


        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [Name_Model], [Description_Spec] FROM [Asset_Type] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)"

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        conn.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            While (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Type_ID.text = (reader["ID"].tostring())
                        Name_Model.text = (reader["Name_Model"].tostring())
                        Description_Spec.text = reader["Description_Spec"].tostring
                    }

            End While
        End If

    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to use some AJAX controls (look for the SDK) or you can write some javascript to get this without reloading the entire page. You should be able to find lots of examples on this site.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `{` and `}` aren't valid in `VB.NET`... you've effectively already created the "block" that `{}` would do in C# by having `While... End While`

Comment: Also, you don't appear to be setting anything for the `@ID` in your SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure about Steve's comment, but I know he is a lot more familiar with VB based on questions of my own he has answered. However I am going to suggest something.

So "Drop downs" typically have 2 pieces of data associated with them.
A `DisplayMember` and a `ValueMember` (also a `SelectedValue` if it's a ComboBoxColumn)

You can reference either, I believe.

Then, you can do what you please with that value using an `If Then` or however you plan on using it.

```
assetValue = YourComboBox.DisplayMember.ToString
YourTextBox.Text = assetValue
```

or

```
If ComboBox.ValueMember = YourIndex Then
       assetValue = Whatever
ElseIf
   ....
End If
```

Give that a try and let me know what you get. I am just throwing ideas out there.